# Find the domain and range of these functions. In each case to find the domain, determine the set of elements that are assigned values by the function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am just confused by the question itself:

> Find the domain and range of these functions. In each case to find the
>   domain, determine the set of elements that are assigned values by the
>   function.

I have a 4 questions under this, however I am just looking to understand the concept so here is only one of them:

> (a) the function that assigns to each nonnegative integer its last
>   digit

What exactly is being looked for in this question and how should I approach solving this? What would a solution to this example problem look like?

Comment: In (a) the elements that are assigned values by the function are the nonnegative integers. This tells you that $\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ is the domain of the function. As last digit it can have elements of set $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$. So that set is the range of it.

Comment: @drhab why is the range only to $9$ and not infinity?

Comment: If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a function then range *can* be defined as the set $\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$. The set $A$ is the domain and the set $B$ is the codomain. So the range is actually identified as the image of $f$. I say *can* because different authors can do it different. I suspect that here this definition is practicized.

Comment: @drhab okay, makes sense thanks!